# WPF Scrollviewer won't show in ListView if contains one item bigger then ListView itself

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, scrollviewer

I have problem in my application where I have ListView with dynamic items. Items might have variable height. In case there is a one item and its height is bigger than height of whole ListView, ScrollViewer won't show.

Problem could be simplified in following example:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication15.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Width="300"
        Height="200">
    <ListView Height="100" Margin="10">
        <ListViewItem Height="150" Background="LimeGreen">
            <TextBlock Text="ITEM" />
        </ListViewItem>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Why is that? Is there anything I can do with it?

Comment: This may be dependent on your theme. I can't reproduce it with the default Windows 7 WPF behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to set the `VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit` attached property to `Pixel`:

```
<ListView Height="100" Margin="10" VirtualizingPanel.ScrollUnit="Pixel">
    <ListViewItem Height="150" Background="LimeGreen">
        <TextBlock Text="ITEM" />
    </ListViewItem>
</ListView>
```